# How to remove "CYGWIN sshd" service from service list in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, cygwin, services

I uninstalled CYGWIN from Windows machine, but still I am seeing the name "CYGWIN sshd" in the service list.

[image: see service list screenshot here]

This is the steps I have followed to uninstall it,

In the cmd prompt, I run the following commands,

```
takeown /r /d y /f cygwin

icacls cygwin /t /grant Everyone:F

rmdir /s /q cygwin
```

Everything was removed successfully, but the name is not removed from the service list. Here my question is how to remove the name from Service list?

Comment: No CYGWIN related items show up in `Control Panel`->`Programs and Features`?

Comment: Nothing has been there in control panel related to CYGWIN. Uninstall is completed successfully. But the name is still present in service list and the status of the service is stopped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you follow the steps in the [CYGWIN FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-service).
If you just want to remove the service from the service list, you can follow these steps from [ghacks.net - how to remove services in windows](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/12/how-to-remove-services-in-windows/).

To remove a service in Windows:

1. Open up the Command Prompt (aka cmd) as administrator (elevated privileges).
2. Type in `sc delete "name of service"` and hit enter. To get the proper full name of a service, open the Windows Services management listing and double click on the service. The proper service name is under "Service Name: #service name#"

Comment: Name of service showed as 'CYGWIN sshd', service name was 'sshd'.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience doing the following is sufficient. First, list active services using:

```
$ cygrunsrv -L
```

Next, **stop** and **remove** the services you want to remove:

```
$ cygrunsrv --stop service_to_remove
$ cygrunsrv --remove service_to_remove
```